# Debezium error when connecting to kafka multi-broker in docker swarm

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-swarm, debezium

when I set up my Swarm with this stack: Kafka(multi-broker), zookeeper, debezium. Kafka and zookeeper are working, can create topic, consumer and producer, but debezium show error: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties. I'm not modifying anything, just default config as docker-stack below:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
   zoo:
      image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
      ports:
         - '2181:2181'
      volumes:
         - zoo-data:/tmp/zookeeper
      deploy:
         replicas: 1
         placement:
            constraints:
               - node.labels.type==zoo
   kafka:
      image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
      ports:
         - target: 9094
           published: 9094
           protocol: tcp
           mode: host
      environment:
         HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
         KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo:2181
         KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
         KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
         KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
         KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
         #KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic1:1:2,Topic2:1:1:compact"
      volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
         - kafka-data:/tmp/kafka-logs
      deploy:
         mode: global
         placement:
            constraints:
               - node.labels.name==kafka
      depends_on:
         - zoo

   debezium:
      image: debezium/connect:0.8
      hostname: connect
      ports:
         - '8083:8083'
      environment:
         BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9094
         GROUP_ID: 1
         CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
         OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      deploy:
         placement:
            constraints:
               - node.labels.type==dbz
      depends_on:
         - kafka
volumes:
   kafka-data:
   zoo-data:
```

When I check docker services log debezium, it show error

```
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    | 2018-08-03 04:33:27,034 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed]
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:45)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:77)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    | Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:258)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:58)
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    |    ... 2 more
shippo_kafka_debezium.1.5l1yhz27r6p2@kafka1    | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.
```

Can anyone show me how to fix this error, I'm new with this stack so, during a few days research, I can't figure out it. Thank you so much !

Comment: I've never seen this `HOSTNAME_COMMAND` variable before. How does that work? How does it get applied to the other variables? Have you gone into the shell of the Kafka containers and looked at the property file to see its correct?

Comment: Could you please share how you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line `HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"` to `HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep 'Node Address:' | cut -d' ' -f 4"`

or just you can use this docker-compose file

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    deploy:
       mode: global
    volumes:
      - /shared_data/zoo1/data:/data
      - /shared_data/zoo1/datalog:/datalog
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep 'Node Address:' | cut -d' ' -f 4"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /shared_data/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```